# subprocess.Popen not recognizing cwd argument

Tags: python, subprocess

I am trying to run a Command Line tool from a python script located in a different directory. I use

```
subprocess.Popen(cmd, cwd="c:\\path\\to\\tool")
```

where cmd is of the format

```
"Toolname.exe /switch1 /switch2 /switch3"
```

Opening a command line in the tool location and executing the above in the python interpreter runs the tool just fine. But if I try to do the same in a different directory, I get

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
File "C:\Python27\lib\subprocess.py", line 390, in __init__
errread, errwrite)
File "C:\Python27\lib\subprocess.py", line 640, in _execute_child
startupinfo)
WindowsError: [Error 2] The system cannot find the file specified
```

To me it looks like cwd is not doing anything. If I open a command prompt in the tool location, and run the command with cwd = "**incorrect** directory", it still works. So, how can I get my cwd argument to work?

Comment: Either double-up your backslashes **or** use a raw string. Don't do both.

Comment: Thanks @CharlesDuffy, I tried both double backslashes alone and raw string alone, but no success. I will edit my question accordingly